# parsing pdb for support vector machine

Tags: python, svm, libsvm, svmlight

I am working on SVM (support vector machine) using python.

My input is pdb file. I have seen number of examples in which dataset is taken. But, in my case, I want to parse 3d structure of protien (.pdb file).

How Can I get the svm from pdb?

Answer (score 0):

SVMa are designed to work with **numbers**. Proteins 3d structures are far from being such. There are few possible options:

- Create some kind of fixed length, numerical representation, this is called **fingerpint** in cheminformatics, and includes dozens of existing methods ie. KlekotaFP; PubChemFP, subFP etc.
- Use a custrom kernel, developed for such structures (like labeled graphs), one such kernels are graph kernels for cheminformatics, ie. those included in [chemcpp](http://chemcpp.sourceforge.net/html/index.html)